# Кодировка файла. Конвертация

Tags: c#

Подскажите еще пожалуйста, проблема с кодировкой. Программа читает данные в XPS файле, создает TXT файл и копирует в него текст и название файла.
Если делаю текстовый файл с текстом, перевожу его для теста в формат .XPS. Все хорошо конвертирует. Если беру готовый файл (который мне присылают) переводит в нечитаемом формате. Можно где и как узнать точную кодировку для считывания и записи ?

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;

namespace CopyTextFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileContent = string.Empty;
            var filePath = string.Empty;
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";


                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Получить путь к указанному файлу
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    //Считать содержимое файла 
                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {

                        // Получить название файла без расширения
                        string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                        // Создать новое имя файла с другим расширением
                        string newFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".txt");

                        using StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(newFilePath, false);
                        write.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ну если вы про этот формат https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification , это ожидаемо, т.к. это ZIP архив, т.е. внутри не текст, а бинарные данные